# How to select data from table with big rows where column like column1%column2

Tags: sql, select

I have a table Product with 240 000 rows.
I want to select from this table data where `idproduct = idproductcomponent`

Output makes a table with 3 columns `A12345678` `35655455952625` `9638520963258960`, so in different column.
Always `idproductcomponent` of `idproducttype` 1 is 0, and `idproductcomponent` of `idproducttype` 2,3 are the same of `idproduct` of `idproducttype` 1.

Pelase, can you share with me any idea for this select ?

[image]

Comment: What's the database?

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: Join the same table ```where idproduct=idproductcomponent```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your database is SQL Server (you don't say which one it is) the query could look like:

```
select
  a.name,
  b.name,
  c.name
from t a
left join t b on b.idproductcomponent = a.idproduct and b.idproducttype = 2
left join t c on c.idproductcomponent = a.idproduct and c.idproducttype = 3
where a.idproducttype = 1
  and a.idproduct = 11163 -- parameter you are searching for
```

To increase the performance of this query you can add the index:

```
create index ix1 on t (idproductcomponent);
```